# Strange behavior of rem in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I tried these two lines of simple Enum.drop_while ... seems easy enough but I don't understand why they turn up differently:

`iex(6)> 1..100 |> Enum.drop_while(fn(x) -> rem(x,10) == 0 end)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]
iex(7)> 1..100 |> Enum.drop_while(fn(x) -> rem(10,x) == 0 end)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43,
 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, ...]`

Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rem x, 10
```

and

```
rem 10, x
```

is not the same thing. That's why you get different results.

See also:

```
iex>div 10, 1
10

iex> div 1, 10
0
```

Comment: Right! I see my fault now! thanks Jonas ... silly one this one!